# How to find the div is loaded or not?

Tags: jquery

i am using a plug-in to load the facebook in to my page. i need to adjust some padding within the loaded content. i can't use the css to do this, because the ajax loading that content finally.

so, i decided to do this using jquery, so i written a interval function to find that div with class loaded or not, once it loaded i need to apply my style. for this i wrote this function

```
$(window).bind('load',function(){
    var faceBook = $('div').hasClass('connect_top');
    var faceInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(faceBook.complete){
            faceBook.css({border:'1px solid red'});
            clearInterval(faceInterval);
        }
    },50)
});
```

but no luck, any one can help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, can you run a callback when your ajax request finishes?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.ajaxComplete()`

So something like

```
$('.connect_top').ajaxComplete(function(){
    $(this).css({border:'1px solid red'});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `div` in the success handler of the AJAX call. If you're using jQuery to make the call it would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({

    // Other AJAX settings...

    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('div.connect_top').css({border:'1px solid red'});
    }
});
```

Comment: No this is loading from facebook plug-in, as well it is loading as a final element of the page. after it loaded only i can able to find this... that's why i wrote the interval function.